# Need trouble shooting of em and rem units for responsive layout

Tags: css

Hello everyone,

I am developing a site for my company and it is advised that the layout should be responsive to present on smartphones, I know that using pixel based layout is a bad idea specially for a responsive layout so I decided to stick with relative / elastic unit but I am in a middle of confusion is that what should I have take either EM or REM, and then a couple of problems are:

- I have to face compounding problem if I go with EM unit.
- I have to face Cross-broswer issues if I go with REM unit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my layouts, I use a combination. It takes more work, but seems to do the job very nicely.

The basis for this is that if a value is invalid, the browser will not use it. In addition, CSS is cascading, so it will always use the latest specified property (if the selector paths are exactly the same).

If I was setting the margin, here is how I would do it:

```
margin-left:1.25em;
margin-left:1rem;
```

Doing it in this format gets the best of both worlds. There are some great articles out there on how to deal with this situation:

- http://css-tricks.com/font-sizing-with-rem/
- http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/font-size-with-rem